# i want to use landscape mode for xml which are in layout-large and portrait for the xml which are in the layout

Tags: android

I want to use landscape mode for xml which are in layout-large and portrait for the xml which are in the layout.
I have used `android:screenOrientation = "portrait"` in all xml which are in layout and `android:screenOrientation = "landscape"` for layout-large xml.it works fine for tablet that it is restrict to the landscape mode but not restrict only portrait mode for android phone.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Fragments for Tablet.

Comment: but layout-large is working for tablet,my problem is layout xml's are not working properly.i have specify screen orientation as portrait but it is working in both mode

Answer (score 0):

I think this is  problem of your device settings.Make sure your settings as follows:

```
Settings==>Display==>uncheck Auto-rotate screen
```

try this

Comment: oh sorry it is device setting...once you uncheck all application included yours will be restricted